# Singleton object memory management

Tags: iphone, memory-management, singleton

In my code, I use a singleton object as a central point in my app to load and cache images the app frequently needs, so I don't have to do resource-intensive memory allocation each time I load an image.

But there are times during the execution of my app where memory usage gets intense and I would like to release the cached image data. Currently, I'm just releasing the UIImage instances from my singleton when I get a memory warning.

I would prefer, however, to be able to release the entire singleton object. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: if its from web u can look at afnetworking uiimageview category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is. Although it's rather likely that the memory usage of this object is negligible compared to the images.

By the nature of a singleton, you need to have an accessor for it, where you will create it if it does not currently exist:

```
+ (MySingletonClass*) mySingleton
{
    if ( mySingleton == nil )
    {
        mySingleton = [[MySingletonClass alloc] init];
    }

    return mySingleton;
}
```

You just need to add another that you call when you want to destroy it:

```
+ (void) destroyMySingleton
{
    [mySingleton release];
    mySingleton = nil;
}
```

If you keep references to it around elsewhere you'll have trouble; don't do that. If you access from multiple threads you'll need to synchronize. Otherwise, it's pretty straightforward -- the getter will recreate when you next need it.

Comment: Cool, thanks! You're right about the really low memory usage of the singleton, but I find it less confusing to just write `[mySingleton release]` instead of creating a new method like `[mySingleton releaseImageData]`

Comment: @ryyst Well, you still need to write a new method -- the class `destroy` method. I suppose you *could* hack it such that `dealloc` resets the static singleton to `nil`, but that would be really nasty.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a singleton accessor for the OpenAL code I'm using.

```
  // Eric Wing. Singleton accessor.  This is how you should ALWAYS get
  // a reference to the sound controller.  Never init your own.
  + (OpenALSoundController*) sharedController
 {
  static OpenALSoundController* shared_sound_controller;
  @synchronized(self)
  {
   if (nil == shared_sound_controller)
    {
     shared_sound_controller = [[OpenALSoundController alloc] init];
    }
  }      
  return shared_sound_controller;
 }
```

OpenAL takes a while to load up so keeping one instance around is exactly what I need. With more than one thread in play (not my situation currently but I want my code to be ported to situations where this is the case) I put a lock on `self`. `@synchronized(self)` does exactly that.

Now I allocated the memory so I'm responsible for releasing it. I could call `[shared_sound_controller autorelease]` in the `+sharedController` accessor method but this may release the controller early, particularly when I have more than one thread and I call the accessor for the first time in a thread that's not the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Any object you create you can just release at any time.  (Presuming you create it and set it's properties.)

```
self.myObject = [[myObjectClass alloc] init];
    // do something with the object
   [self.myObject release];       // anytime that you are not using the object

self.myObject = nil; // will also work if you've set the @property (retain, nonatomic)
```

Comment: Are you sure that applies to singleton objects as well?

Comment: I am not.  I don't see why it wouldn't, but don't know for sure.

Comment: Actually when that singleton object will be released from the memory?